# Background image that always scales so that any normal background color wouldn't appear

Tags: css, background-image

I wonder if there is a hack that would resize the image in the way that it would always cover the whole browser window. It should also keep the image´s aspect ratio.

Comment: which image you want to scale to the whole window?? if it is a just a image , then do you have a hig resoltion image ready ?? I know how to do that , let me know what you need

Answer (score 0):

this website http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/ has a great writeup on this.

Basically just use as the style for your bg

```
#bg {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

About your requirement to maintain the aspect ration AT THE SAME TIME as make it cover the whole window, I don't think it's achievable, you either sacrifice aspect ratio or coverage

Comment: Hello, Ok thanks! I tried to achieve it with javascript but without results.

Comment: @ppp , i think the above solution won't work for IE , try and see if it works , otherwise i have some code which sets...for IE also

Answer (score 0):

try this code through jquery

```
 var docHeight = Math.max(

            $(document).height(),

            $(window).height(),

            /* For opera: */

            document.documentElement.clientHeight

        );

        var docWidth = Math.max(

            $(document).width(),

            $(window).width(),

            /* For opera: */

            document.documentElement.clientWidth

        );

        $("selector").css({

            "height":docHeight,

            "width":docWidth

        });
```